# MongoDb Shell - how to show <document> result which one is updated?

Tags: mongodb

Mongo update query as below

```
db.personnel.update({"organization._id":'o4C8aSHbEBSaAuKog'},{$set:{name:'ghostsads'}}, {multi:true})
```

and it shows as

> WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 17, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 16 })

How can find out updated documents using same query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i want to share that I have tried that trick! it working!.

```
var criteria_find = {"organization._id":'o4C8aSHbEBSaAuKog'};
var criteria_set = {"organization._id":'o4C8aSHbEBSaAuKog'},{$set:{name:'ghostsads'}};
var projection = {multi:true};

var check = db.personnel.find(criteria_find);

if(check){

check.forEach(function(els){

print('personnel_id was effected : ' + els._id);

db.personnel.update(criteria, projection);

})

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Mongo does not return this information. As it is written in the documentation update returns [WriteResult](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/#WriteResult)

> WriteResult object contains the number of documents that matched the
>   query condition, the number of documents inserted by the update, and
>   the number of documents modified

So you can only see

```
WriteResult({
  "nMatched" : 1,
  "nUpserted" : 0,
  "nModified" : 1
})
```

how many documents matched your query, how many of them were upserted and at last how many were updated. In your case 16 of them.

If you really want to see them, you can do this manually by checking before the update how many documents did not have a `name` field or had name field not equal to your `'ghostsads'` string.

Comment: hmmm... because i have many data for loop for update, that why i need which one document is updated.btw. thank for info.

Comment: @FaridBlaster yes, and I told you that mongo does not provide such information. Also in your case not `one` document was updated, but 16 of them.